# java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: File Not found

Tags: java, file, exception, jena

I am trying to read an Ontology using Jena. I have a file Pizza.owl in the correct directory shown in the code, but I still get an error that the file is not found.

```
public static void ReadOntology(){

OntModel onto = ModelFactory.createOntologyModel(OntModelSpec.OWL_MEM, null);
String inputFileName = "C:\\Users\\najib\\studies\\pizza.owl";

try {
    Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(Operations.class); 

    PropertyConfigurator.configure("C://Users//najib//Downloads//apache-jena-2.12.0//jena-log4j.properties");
//create the reasoning model using the base
    OntModel model = ModelFactory.createOntologyModel();
// use the FileManager to find the input file
    InputStream in = FileManager.get().open(inputFileName);
    if (in == null) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("File: " + inputFileName + " not found");
    }
    model.read(in, "");
//to list classes
    ExtendedIterator<OntClass> classes = model.listClasses();
    while (classes.hasNext()) {
        OntClass cls = (OntClass) classes.next();
        System.out.println("Classes: " + cls.getLocalName());
        for (ExtendedIterator<OntClass> i = cls.listSubClasses(true); i.hasNext();) {
            OntClass c = (OntClass) i.next();
            System.out.print(" " + c.getLocalName() + "\n");
        } // end for
    }
} catch (Exception e) {
    System.out.println(e);
    }
}
```

}

I get the following error: `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: File: C:\Users\najib\studies\pizza.owl not found`

Comment: Which OS do you use? Does java have the necessary access rights?

Comment: @markus I use Windows 7. I believe that Eclipse has the rights since it can access the `apache jena proprieties file`

Comment: What's the class of FileManager? Own implementation?

Comment: @Naveen, when I did, I got `File: C://Users//najib//studies//pizza.owl not found`

Comment: You only need a single slash: `C:/Users/najib/studies/pizza.owl`

Comment: IllegalArgumentException? Strange choice. That's for code to report that it got passed a bad argument, not for it to report that it passed other code a bad argument. I recommend [FileNotFoundException](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/FileNotFoundException.html).

Comment: @markus `FileManager` is a JENA class to load OWL/RDF file. https://jena.apache.org/documentation/javadoc/jena/com/hp/hpl/jena/util/FileManager.html

Comment: Did you try `C:/Users/najib/studies/pizza.owl` Why are you using double backslashes anyway ?

Comment: @singe31: Double backslashes in source code produce single backslashes in the string, since backslash is the escape character.

Comment: @singe31 I tried that too. I feel it's not really a syntax issue. rather something wrong with the function

Comment: Why are you using forward slashes in `PropertyConfigurator.configure("C://Users//najib//Downloads//apache-jena-2.12.0//jena-log4j.properties");`? I'd expect that to be a problem.

Comment: Maybe this is also a part of your solution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18144131/loading-resources-with-filemanager-doesnt-work-in-jena-2-10-1

Comment: @Markus, so could it be therefore a versioning error?

Comment: I am not a user of Apache Lena but a version issue or a issue with the loaded properties file (2013.08.09 14:21:00 [main] LocationMapper WARN: Error in configuration file: null)

Answer (score 0):

When I read the `javadoc` of [`FileManager`](https://jena.apache.org/documentation/javadoc/jena/com/hp/hpl/jena/util/FileManager.html), I see you have to prefix your file parameter with `"file:"`

So (without testing this answer) I suggest to try it with:

```
String inputFileName = "file:/C:/Users/najib/studies/pizza.owl";
```